# Extend Aurelia Validation Rules on a per class basis

Tags: aurelia

If I have a class

```
export class Person {
    public name: string = "";
    public foo: string = "";
}

ValidationRules
    .ensure((p :Person) => p.name)
    .required()
    .withMessage("name is required")
    .on(Person);
```

Is there any way to extend those rules on a per controller basis?  For example in my `App` class I also want to ensure the `foo` property is set, however adding this as a rule here seems to override the `name` rule from the above code.

```
export class App {

    public person: Person = new Person();
    @observable
    public message: string = "";

    constructor(public vc: ValidationController, public vld: Validator) {

        ValidationRules
          .ensure((p: Person) => p.foo).required().withMessage("foo is required").on(this.person);


        this.vc.addObject(this.person);
        this.vc.validate();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes that's possible, but it requires a slightly different approach.

There are 2 important things to note here:

1. The fluent api initializer (static method `ensure()` on `ValidationRules`) always instantiates a **new** `FluentEnsure` object. It doesn't look for existing stuff - not even if you finalize on the same target. To extend a ruleset with more rules, you need to call `.ensure()` on the existing ruleset.
2. The finalizer (instance method `on()` on `FluentEnsure`) stores the rules in the `.prototype.__rules__` (if it's a Function) or `.__rules__` property of the target you pass in and will **overwrite** any existing one.

In other words when you finalize on an instance of `Person`, you're storing a brand new rules object on `person.__rules__` which effectively **hides** `Person.prototype.__rules__`.

For the record, the static methods `Rules.set(target, rules)` and `Rules.get(target)` are wrappers around the `.__rules__` property. You'll definitely want to call those and not try to access the property directly.

Now you might think something like `Rules.get(Person).ensure(...).on(person)` but that would also modify the original rules on `Person.prototype`.

So how to work with that?

#### Enter tags

It can get messy with fetching and combining rulesets, but here's the basic idea:

```
export class Person {}
ValidationRules.ensure(p => p.name).required().on(Person)
```

And elsewhere:

```
Rules.get(Person).ensure(p => p.foo).required().tag("foo");
```

And elsewhere:

```
Rules.get(Person).ensure(p => p.bar).required().tag("1234");
```

Then when it's time to validate:

```
const allRules = Rules.get(Person); // "1234" is included
const fooRules = ValidationRules.untaggedRules(allRules)
         .concat(ValidationRules.taggedRules(allRules, "foo"); "1234" not included
vc.addObject(person);
vc.validate({ fooRules });
```

#### Or hand roll something

I've never actually used tags myself before and I've seen an issue or two regarding them. You could also do something similar yourself if you want more control/transparency:

```
export class Person {
    public static scopedRules: { [scope: string]: any } = Object.create(null);
}
ValidationRules.ensure(p => p.name).required().on(Person)
```

And elsewhere:

```
Person.scopedRules.foo = Object.create(null);
ValidationRules.ensure(p => p.foo).required().on(Person.scopedRules.foo)
```

Then when it's time to validate:

```
const rules = Rules.get(Person).concat(Rules.get(Person.scopedRules.foo));
vc.addObject(person);
vc.validate({ rules });
```

Of course this is just a "simplest possible thing" example. In a real world scenario you'd probably have your rule storage/retrieval/merging etc tucked away somewhere.